# solidity, how to keep it DRY for similar but different structs?

Tags: solidity

I have a bunch of Actions in the dApp i'm building. Each action has different data associated with it. At the same time, they have a few common fields. Is there a way to model this to handle the different data associated with it?

Or do I have to make different structs for each action type I have?

Note that If I have 1 struct for all my action types it makes my code cleaner to write. I.e. I can keep the loop and common testing conditions DRY.

If I have multiple structs I have to loop through each different struct so that adds one loop per struct (plus other code that tests common members). Given this concern, is there a suggested way to handle structs with different data?

```
enum ActionType { A, B, C }
struct Action {
    ActionType actionType;
    string name;
    string description;
    uint createdAt;
    // should i put optional data fields?
    string someFieldOnlyExistsForA;
    bool someBoolOnlyExistsForB;
    uint someIntOnlyExistsForC;
}
```

//example what i mean

```
Action[] actions;

for (uint i = 0; i < actions.length; i++) {
    if (actions[i].createdAt < now - 1000) {
        if (actions[i].actionType == A) {do something with the string field}
        if (actions[i].actionType == B) {do something with the bool field}
        if (actions[i].actionType == C) {do something with the int field}
    }
}
```

vs

```
for (uint i = 0; i < A_actions.length; i++) {
    if (Aactions[i].createdAt < now - 1000) {
    }
}
for (uint i = 0; i < B_actions.length; i++) {
    if (Bactions[i].createdAt < now - 1000) {
    }
}
for (uint i = 0; i < C_actions.length; i++) {
    if (C_actions[i].createdAt < now - 1000) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand, you are showing the solution. what is your problem?

Comment: I don't understand which is the 'accepted'/'recommended' way to do things and why. I couldn't find anything on struct inheritance and doing it like option 1 implicitly has more fields saved into storage that are not necessary. Meanwhile option 2 is less DRY. Was wondering if there is a recommended way of handling this type of situation